# Django and redis adding :1 to keys

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-cache, django-redis

I'm using [django-redis](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis) to store some data on my website, and I have a problem where Redis is adding :1 at the beginning so my key looks like this: `:1:my_key`

I'm not sure why is it doing this, I've read the documentation on django-redis and I couldn't find anything related, so my guess it has something to do with redis but I can't figure out what.

In my settings.py I have the regular:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://xxxxx/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
       }
   }
}
```

And in my tasks.py I set keys like the documentation says:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set(my_key, my_value, 3600)
```

So now I can't get the values using the `cache.get(my_key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:1` it's version

`cache.set(key, value, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None)`

You can remove it by set empty string:

`cache.set("foo", "bar",version='')`

In the redis you will get:

`::foo`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django Documentation on [Cache Key transformation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation):

> "The cache key provided by a user is not used verbatim – it is combined with the cache prefix and key version to provide a final cache key. By default, the three parts are joined using colons to produce a final string:"

```py
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return "%s:%s:%s" % (key_prefix, version, key)
```

The [version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#version) defaults to `1` and the [key-prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#key-prefix) defaults to an empty string. Therefore, your resulting key looks like `:1:my_key`.

In case you want to change the version and key-prefix, you can do this in your CACHES settings as shown below:

```py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://xxxxx/0",
        "VERSION": "my_version",
        "KEY_PREFIX": "my_prefix",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
       }
   }
}
```

In that case, the code `cache.set(my_key, my_value, 3600)` would create the key `my_prefix:my_version:my_key`. The cache settings for VERSION and KEY_PREFIX would then also allow you to get the required value by using the key "my_key", so `cache.get(my_key)` will get you the correct value.